# Should I choose a mirror server?

Tags: 20.04, mirrors

After installing Ubuntu 20.04 on my desktop computer, should I select a mirror server? Where would I find what my options are?

Comment: Are you using a mirror currently; use `sudo apt update` to view where you're getting packages from.  I get lines like `Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease [269 kB]` (I'm on *impish* or the development release) and am using the main site (so it's `archive.ubuntu.com`). Do you see any country codes in front of yours?   Official mirrors can be seen at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu for more details maybe too (first pic shows mirror selection using GUI tool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting a mirror server is easy, but not required. The Ubuntu installer will try to select an appropriate mirror for you.

If you want to change it,

1. Find your Shortcut Bar
2. Click on the little nine-box grid (or tap your <kbd>Super</kbd> key)
3. Search for (and click on) **Software & Updates**
4. Click on the **Ubuntu Software** tab.
5. Look for the **Download From** field. That's the list of servers. Select one.

[image]